# PineScript: Is it possible to use alerts from external indicator in my strategy?

Tags: tradingview-api

If I add external indicator to my chart (with my strategy already on the chart),
then I can get variables (created with "plot()" in indicators) from external indicator.

With code:

`external_indicator1 = input.source(defval=close)`

But is it possible to get in my strategy "Alerts" from these external indicators ?

or if indicator write But/Sell signals with "plotshape()"

`plotshape(buySignal, title="Buy Label", text="Buy",style=shape.labelup,color=longColor)`

Is it possible to get this "Buy" signal in my strategy ?

For tests I have added external indicator to my chart,
and as a "Source" see only lines made with "plot()" commands.. Not see how to get "Buy/Sell" messages, which writes this indicator.